# No values is getting shown after logging custom event using Facebook Analytics

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-analytics

I'm using Facebook Analytics in my app and wants to analyse which 'signup method' from Facebook and Email/Password users are using more.

For this I followed the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android).

Here's what I tried:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this);

Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
bundle1.putString("methodUsed", "email_password");
logger.logEvent("signup_method", bundle1);
```

Though the event got shown in the 'Events' tab of the dashboard, the space under the 'Value' row is empty which should have been `"facebook"`.

Please **let me know** if I'm doing anything incorrectly here and how can I get the value also shown in the dashboard?

Comment: The space under the "value" column should be empty with your code. Value would be used for the valueToSum parameter. However, you should be seeing data under the "parameters" column. You should be seeing "methodUsed - email_password" (or "methodUsed - facebook" - assuming this is in some code that you didn't include in your question?). Are you seeing either of those? If not can you post the code for logging methodUsed = "facebook"?

Comment: where is this "parameters" column?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice you were looking at the "Events" tab. "parameters" is in the "Event Debugging" tab.

Comment: there isn't anything under "parameter" too.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Parameter value does not appear. What is your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters won't be shown on an event's page under the events tab.

For your use case, you'll want to look in the Breakdowns tab. Create a breakdown for your "signup_method" event, and under "Breakdown 1", select "methodUsed" as your breakdown parameter. Then click Save, and you should see a breakdown of how many people used each signup method.

Comment: Great! I can see different "`methodUsed`" here. So, this is how I would be able to see the "`value`"/"`parameter`" of any custom event?

Comment: Yes, this is how you would see a breakdown by parameters for any custom (or predefined) event.

Comment: can you help me with the steps to see breakdown with screenshots, i am not finding any breakdown action in a events page